# Select count of grouped Products AND the cheapest price for each product

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the distinct products, grouped by all columns except the ID, and the cheapest bid for that type of product. Sometimes, there may be no bids for that product, so I'll need to left join to account for those.

I'll add the desired output below and also a sort-of pseudo query to help explain.

If it helps, you can imagine a product search page. When the user searches, it groups all the same products together. These products can be sold by many different sellers but we want to only show it once within the results, along with the cheapest price for that product at the time of the search.

**Data I want returned**

```
SELECT count(Name), Size, Weight, Color, BidID, Status, min(Price)
-- joins go here --
-- group by Size, Weight, Color, BidID, Status
```

Will also require WHERE clauses, which are built based on filters used by end user. Examples:

```
WHERE Status = 'Active' and Weight = '1kg'
WHERE Status = 'Active'
WHERE Size = '1m' and Weight in ('1kg', '2kg')
```

**Products Table**

```
| ProductID (PK) | Name        | Size | Weight | Color  |
| --------       | --------    | -----| -----  | -----  | 
| 1              | Black Table | 1m   | 2kg    | Black  | 
| 2              | Purple Table| 1m   | 3kg    | Purple | 
| 3              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 
| 4              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 
| 5              | Black Table | 1m   | 2kg    | Black  | 
| 6              | Purple Table| 1m   | 3kg    | Purple |
| 7              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 
| 8              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  |
```

**Bids Table**

```
| BidID (PK)     | ProductID   | Status      | Price   |
| --------       | -------     | --------    | -----   |
| 1              |  1          | Active      | 123.5   |
| 2              |  1          | Active      | 325.99  |
| 3              |  1          | Active      | 85.99   |
| 4              |  3          | Cancelled   | 315.99  |
| 5              |  4          | Active      | 113.5   |
| 6              |  3          | Cancelled   | 305.99  |
| 7              |  1          | Active      | 82.99   |
| 8              |  2          | Active      | 345.99  |
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT EXAMPLE**

```
| Count          | Name        | Size | Weight | Color  | BidID |CheapestPrice |
| --------       | --------    | -----| -----  | -----  | ----- | -----     |
| 38             | Black Table | 1m   | 2kg    | Black  |  1    | 123.5
| 21             | Purple Table| 1m   | 3kg    | Purple |  2    | 89.95
| 13             | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  |  3    | 65.94
```

Comment: The format is fine in preview. Anyone else just seeing a mess for the tables?

Comment: Everyone - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Please show us your index details

Comment: No indexes yet. The queries can vary heavily, depending on all the filters used by the user. Any suggestions welcome here, thanks!

Comment: It's an odd design where product has no uniqueness.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking for help if it was easy ;) There's more complexity around why this is the case but it isn't relevant.

Comment: Looks easy to me see posted answer.

Comment: Pure wizardry. As you may have guessed, I'm pretty new to this. Your solution seems great to me so far, thank you. Wish I knew what it was doing :)

Comment: @P.Salmon if you're able to help with some updated requirements - I'd love you even more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781349/select-count-of-grouped-products-and-the-cheapest-price-for-each-product-where-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have version 8 or above (and you should by now) allocate a row number to the lowest bid an union products with no bids

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PRDUCTS,BIDS;

CREATE TABLE Prducts
( ProductID INT, Name  VARCHAR(20), Size VARCHAR(20), Weight VARCHAR(20), Color  VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO PRDUCTS VALUE
( 1              , 'Black Table' , '1m'   , '2kg'    , 'Black'  ), 
( 2              , 'Purple Table', '1m'   , '3kg'    , 'Purple' ), 
( 3              , 'Small Table' , '1m'   , '3kg'    , 'Black'  ), 
( 4              , 'Small Table' , '1m'   , '3kg'    , 'Black'  ), 
( 5              , 'Black Table' , '1m'   , '2kg'    , 'Black'  ), 
( 6              , 'Purple Table', '1m'   , '3kg'    , 'Purple' ),
( 7              , 'Small Table' , '1m'   , '3kg'    , 'Black'  ), 
( 8              , 'Small Table' , '1m'   , '3kg'    , 'Black'  ),
( 9              , 'BOMBASTO'    , '1m'   , '3kg'    , 'Black'  ); 

CREATE TABLE Bids
( BidID    INT     , ProductID  INT  , Status VARCHAR(20) ,     Price DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO BIDS VALUES
( 1              ,  1          , 'Active'      , 123.5   ),
( 2              ,  1          , 'Active'      , 325.99  ),
( 3              ,  1          , 'Active'      , 85.99   ),
( 4              ,  3          , 'Cancelled'   , 315.99  ),
( 5              ,  4          , 'Active'      , 113.5   ),
( 6              ,  3          , 'Cancelled'   , 305.99  ),
( 7              ,  1          , 'Active'      , 82.99   ),
( 8              ,  2          , 'Active'      , 345.99  );

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT P.PRODUCTID PPID,NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR
       ,B.BIDID,B.PRODUCTID AS BPID,STATUS,PRICE
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR ORDER BY PRICE) RN
FROM PRDUCTS P
JOIN BIDS B ON B.PRODUCTID = P.PRODUCTID
) 
SELECT PPID,NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR,PRICE FROM CTE 
WHERE  RN = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCTID,NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR,NULL
FROM   PRDUCTS P
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.NAME = P.NAME      AND
                                         CTE.WEIGHT = P.WEIGHT  AND
                                         CTE.COLOR = P.COLOR);

+------+--------------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| PPID | NAME         | SIZE | WEIGHT | COLOR  | PRICE  |
+------+--------------+------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 | Black Table  | 1m   | 2kg    | Black  |  82.99 |
|    2 | Purple Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Purple | 345.99 |
|    4 | Small Table  | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 113.50 |
|    9 | BOMBASTO     | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  |   NULL |
+------+--------------+------+--------+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.003 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole Query :

```
SELECT
    Count( p.ProductID ) AS Count,
    p.`Name`,
    p.Size,
    p.Weight,
    p.Color,
    b.BidID,
    b.Price 
FROM
    products AS p
    LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    MIN( bi.Price ) AS Price,
    bi.BidID AS BidID,
    bi.ProductID AS ProductID 
FROM
    bids AS bi
    JOIN (
SELECT
    bc.TimeOfBid AS bids_last_filled 
FROM
    bids AS bc 
WHERE
    bc.ProductID = ProductID 
    AND bc.`Status` = 'Filled' 
ORDER BY
    bc.TimeOfBid DESC 
    LIMIT 1 
    ) BLF 
WHERE
    bi.`Status` = 'Active' 
    AND bi.TimeOfBid > BLF.bids_last_filled 
GROUP BY
    bi.ProductID 
    ) b ON p.ProductID = b.ProductID 
GROUP BY
    p.`Name`
```

The above code is for :
[Select count of grouped Products AND the cheapest price for each product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73771420/select-count-of-grouped-products-and-the-cheapest-price-for-each-product?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Check it out.