# SELECT count of grouped Products AND the cheapest price for each product WHERE not yet filled

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the distinct products, grouped by all columns except the ID, and the cheapest bid for that type of product. Sometimes, there may be no bids for that product, so I'll need to left join to account for those.

I'll add the desired output below and also a sort-of pseudo query to help explain.

If it helps, you can imagine a product search page. When the user searches, it groups all the same products together. These products can be sold by many different sellers but we want to only show it once within the results, along with the cheapest price for that product at the time of the search.

Important: An 'Active' bid can be cancelled, which overrides the status for that row. But, due to how this system works, if the bid is accepted (filled), it creates a new bid row for that ProductID. So, I need the cheapest bid that is **still active** and doesn't have a 'filled' bid after, based on the `TimeOfBid` field.

**Statuses**

1. Cancelled - Updates the BidID from Active to Cancelled (overriding)
2. Active - An active bid
3. Filled - This is a new row. If it's the
   latest row, it means there is no longer any active bids.

**Data I want returned**

```
SELECT count(Name), Size, Weight, Color, BidID, Status, min(Price)
-- WHERE the bid is still active (has 'Active' status and no 'Filled' bid with later time) --
-- AND is the cheapest price
-- group by Size, Weight, Color, BidID, Status
```

Will also require WHERE clauses, which are built based on filters used by end user. Examples:

```
WHERE Status = 'Active' and Weight = '1kg'
WHERE Status = 'Active'
WHERE Size = '1m' and Weight in ('1kg', '2kg')
```

**Products Table**

```
| ProductID (PK) | Name        | Size | Weight | Color  |
| --------       | --------    | -----| -----  | -----  | 
| 1              | Black Table | 1m   | 2kg    | Black  | 
| 2              | Purple Table| 1m   | 3kg    | Purple | 
| 3              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 
| 4              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 
| 5              | Black Table | 1m   | 2kg    | Black  | 
| 6              | Purple Table| 1m   | 3kg    | Purple |
| 7              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 
| 8              | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  | 
| 9              | Big Table   | 2m   | 4kg    | Gray   |
```

**Bids Table**

```
| BidID (PK)     | ProductID   | Status      | Price   | TimeOfBid           |
| --------       | -------     | --------    | -----   | ------------------- |
| 1              |  1          | Filled      | 123.5   | 2022-09-20 02:51:41 | <= ID 1 now has no active bid
| 2              |  2          | Cancelled   | 325.99  | 2022-09-20 02:50:28 |
| 3              |  1          | Active      | 85.99   | 2022-09-20 01:16:24 | 
| 4              |  3          | Cancelled   | 315.99  | 2022-09-20 01:15:58 |
| 5              |  4          | Active      | 113.5   | 2022-09-20 01:15:39 | <= Cheapest for ID 4
| 6              |  3          | Cancelled   | 305.99  | 2022-09-20 01:15:12 |
| 7              |  1          | Active      | 82.99   | 2022-09-20 01:14:46 | 
| 8              |  2          | Active      | 345.99  | 2022-09-20 01:13:33 | <= Cheapest for ID 2
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT EXAMPLE**

```
| Count          | Name        | Size | Weight | Color  | BidID | CheapestPrice |
| --------       | --------    | -----| -----  | -----  | ----- | -----        |
| 38             | Black Table | 1m   | 2kg    | Black  |  1    | 123.5
| 21             | Purple Table| 1m   | 3kg    | Purple |  2    | 89.95
| 13             | Small Table | 1m   | 3kg    | Black  |  3    | 65.94
| 6              | Big Table   | 2m   | 4kg    | Gray   |  NULL | NULL
```

Someone helped me get close yesterday (I failed to give the full picture) with the below query. It just doesn't take into account that the bids are overridden with newer Bid rows with Status set to 'Filled'. It also doesn't return the count() of grouped products.

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT P.PRODUCTID PPID,NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR
       ,B.BIDID,B.PRODUCTID AS BPID,STATUS,PRICE
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR ORDER BY PRICE) RN
FROM PRDUCTS P
JOIN BIDS B ON B.PRODUCTID = P.PRODUCTID
) 
SELECT PPID,NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR,PRICE FROM CTE 
WHERE  RN = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCTID,NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,COLOR,NULL
FROM   PRDUCTS P
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.NAME = P.NAME      AND
                                         CTE.WEIGHT = P.WEIGHT  AND
                                         CTE.COLOR = P.COLOR);
```

Comment: Your desired output does not match your sample data, BID's does not contain a ProductID of 9 for example which is in your output. Please update your desired output using your sample data that you've provided. Also, the first row in your desired output shows a price of 123.5 which is mapped to ProductID 1, BidID 1 - which is FILLED, you state you only want ACTIVE.

Answer (score -1):

Whole Query :

```
SELECT
    Count( p.ProductID ) AS Count,
    p.`Name`,
    p.Size,
    p.Weight,
    p.Color,
    b.BidID,
    b.Price 
FROM
    products AS p
    LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    MIN( bi.Price ) AS Price,
    bi.BidID AS BidID,
    bi.ProductID AS ProductID 
FROM
    bids AS bi
    JOIN (
SELECT
    bc.TimeOfBid AS bids_last_filled 
FROM
    bids AS bc 
WHERE
    bc.ProductID = ProductID 
    AND bc.`Status` = 'Filled' 
ORDER BY
    bc.TimeOfBid DESC 
    LIMIT 1 
    ) BLF 
WHERE
    bi.`Status` = 'Active' 
    AND bi.TimeOfBid > BLF.bids_last_filled 
GROUP BY
    bi.ProductID 
    ) b ON p.ProductID = b.ProductID 
GROUP BY
    p.`Name`
```

Query Explain : https://prnt.sc/QloA5UuQRqcQ

Query Result :
https://prnt.sc/uyOnjGayvGfy